# how can I be able to signup

Tags: jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, jstl

I try to create my sign up form page accompagnied by its servlet. But when I try to sign up it doesn't work. The problem here is : When `InscriptionForm` begins to recover fiels from that JSP, it references `null` values. How can use this mvc to sign up please ? xD

**JSP**

> ```
> <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
> <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
> <meta charset="utf-8" />
> <title>Inscription</title>
> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
>   href="<c:url value="/inc/form.css"/>" />
> </head>
> <body>
>   <c:import url="/inc/barre.jsp" />
>   <form method="post" action="<c:url value="/inscription" />" enctype="multipart/form-data">
>       <fieldset>
>           <legend>Inscription</legend>
>
>           <label for="email">Adresse email <span class="requis">*</span></label>
>           <input type="text" class="btn" id="email" name="email"
>               value="<c:out value="${utilisateur.email}"/>" size="20"
>               maxlength="60" /> <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['email']}</span>
>           <br /> <label for="motdepasse">Mot de passe <span
>               class="requis">*</span></label> <input type="password" class="btn"
>               id="motdepasse" name="motdepasse" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
>           <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['motdepasse']}</span> <br /> <label
>               for="confirmation">Confirmation du mot de passe <span
>               class="requis">*</span></label> <input type="password" class="btn"
>               id="confirmation" name="confirmation" value="" size="20"
>               maxlength="20" /> <br /> <label for="nom">Pseudo <span
>               class="requis">*</span></label> <input type="text" id="nom" class="btn"
>               name="nom" value="<c:out value="${utilisateur.nom}"/>" size="20"
>               maxlength="20" /> <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['nom']}</span>
>           <br /> <label for="siteweb">Site-web </label> <input type="text"
>               class="btn" id="siteweb" name="siteweb" value="" size="20"
>               maxlength="20" /> <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['siteweb']}</span>
>           <br /> <label for="avatar">Avatar </label> <input type="file"
>               id="avatar" name="avatar" value="<c:out value="${nomFichier}"/>" />
>           <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['avatar']}</span><br /> <label
>               for="localisation">Localisation </label> <input type="text"
>               class="btn" id="localisation" name="localisation" value="" size="20"
>               maxlength="20" /> <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['localisation']}</span><br />
>           <label for="description">Description </label>
>           <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
>           <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['description']}</span> <br /> <input
>               type="submit" value="Inscription" class="sansLabel" /> <input
>               type="reset" value="Remettre à zéro" /> <br />
>
>
>           <p class="${empty form.erreurs ? 'succes' : 'erreur'}">${form.resultat}</p>
>       </fieldset>
>   </form>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

**Servlet**

> ```
> package com.forum.form;
>
> import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
> import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
> import java.io.File;
> import java.io.FileOutputStream;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.io.InputStream;
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
> import java.util.Collection;
> import java.util.Date;
> import java.util.HashMap;
> import java.util.Map;
>
> import javax.servlet.ServletException;
> import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
> import javax.servlet.http.Part;
>
> import org.hibernate.Query;
> import org.hibernate.Session;
> import org.hibernate.Transaction;
>
> import com.forum.beans.Utilisateur;
> import com.forum.dao.UtilisateurDAO;
> import com.forum.utils.HibernateUtils;
>
> import eu.medsea.mimeutil.MimeUtil;
>
> public final class InscriptionForm {
>   private static final String CHAMP_EMAIL = "email";
>   private static final String CHAMP_PASS = "motdepasse";
>   private static final String CHAMP_CONF = "confirmation";
>   private static final String CHAMP_NOM = "nom";
>   private static final String CHAMP_DESC = "description";
>   private static final String CHAMP_LOC = "localisation";
>   private static final String CHAMP_SW = "siteweb";
>   public static final String CHAMP_IMAGE = "avatar";
>   public static final int TAILLE_TAMPON = 10240; // 10 ko
>   public static final String CHEMIN = "E:\\Bibliothèque logicielle\\workspace\\projetForum\\WebContent\\images\\bd\\";
>
>   private String resultat;
>   private static Map<String, String> erreurs = new HashMap<String, String>();
>
>   public String getResultat() {
>       return resultat;
>   }
>
>   public Map<String, String> getErreurs() {
>       return erreurs;
>   }
>
>   public Utilisateur inscrireUtilisateur(HttpServletRequest request) {
>       String email = getValeurChamp(request, CHAMP_EMAIL);
>       String motDePasse = getValeurChamp(request, CHAMP_PASS);
>       String confirmation = getValeurChamp(request, CHAMP_CONF);
>       String nom = getValeurChamp(request, CHAMP_NOM);
>       String description = getValeurChamp(request, CHAMP_DESC);
>       String localisation = getValeurChamp(request, CHAMP_LOC);
>       String siteweb = getValeurChamp(request, CHAMP_SW);
>       String image = getValeurChamp(request, CHAMP_IMAGE);
>       System.out.println("*********************"+email + motDePasse + confirmation + nom
>               + description + localisation + siteweb + image);
>       try {
>           validationEmail(email);
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           setErreur(CHAMP_EMAIL, e.getMessage());
>       }
>
>       try {
>           validationMotsDePasse(motDePasse, confirmation);
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           setErreur(CHAMP_PASS, e.getMessage());
>       }
>
>       try {
>           validationNom(nom);
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           setErreur(CHAMP_NOM, e.getMessage());
>       }
>       if (image != null)
>           try {
>               image = validationImage(request, CHEMIN);
>           } catch (Exception e) {
>               setErreur(CHAMP_IMAGE, e.getMessage());
>           }
>
>       Utilisateur utilisateur = new Utilisateur(email, motDePasse, nom,
>               localisation, siteweb, description);
>       utilisateur.setAvatar(image);
>
>       if (erreurs.isEmpty()) {
>           resultat = "Succès de l'inscription.";
>           createORupdate(utilisateur, request);
>       } else {
>           resultat = "Échec de l'inscription.";
>       }
>
>       return utilisateur;
>   }
>
>   private String validationImage(HttpServletRequest request, String chemin)
>           throws Exception {
>       /*
>        * Récupération du contenu du champ image du formulaire. Il faut ici
>        * utiliser la méthode getPart().
>        */
>       SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
>       Date aujourdhui = new Date();
>       String nomFichier = formater.format(aujourdhui).replace(" ", "")
>               .replace("/", "").replace(":", "").replace("-", "");
>       InputStream contenuFichier = null;
>       try {
>           Part part = request.getPart(CHAMP_IMAGE);
>           nomFichier = nomFichier + getNomFichier(part);
>
>           /*
>            * Si la méthode getNomFichier() a renvoyé quelque chose, il s'agit
>            * donc d'un champ de type fichier (input type="file").
>            */
>           if (nomFichier != null && !nomFichier.isEmpty()) {
>               /*
>                * Antibug pour Internet Explorer, qui transmet pour une raison
>                * mystique le chemin du fichier local à la machine du client...
>                * 
>                * Ex : C:/dossier/sous-dossier/fichier.ext
>                * 
>                * On doit donc faire en sorte de ne sélectionner que le nom et
>                * l'extension du fichier, et de se débarrasser du superflu.
>                */
>               nomFichier = nomFichier.substring(
>                       nomFichier.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).substring(
>                       nomFichier.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
>
>               /* Récupération du contenu du fichier */
>               contenuFichier = part.getInputStream();
>
>               /* Extraction du type MIME du fichier depuis l'InputStream */
>               MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.MagicMimeMimeDetector");
>               Collection<?> mimeTypes = MimeUtil.getMimeTypes(contenuFichier);
>
>               /*
>                * Si le fichier est bien une image, alors son en-tête MIME
>                * commence par la chaîne "image"
>                */
>               if (mimeTypes.toString().startsWith("image")) {
>                   /* Ecriture du fichier sur le disque */
>                   ecrireFichier(contenuFichier, nomFichier, chemin);
>               } else {
>                   throw new Exception(
>                           "Le fichier envoyé doit être une image.");
>               }
>           }
>       } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
>           /*
>            * Exception retournée si la taille des données dépasse les limites
>            * définies dans la section <multipart-config> de la déclaration de
>            * notre servlet d'upload dans le fichier web.xml
>            */
>           e.printStackTrace();
>           throw new Exception("Le fichier envoyé ne doit pas dépasser 1Mo.");
>       } catch (IOException e) {
>           /*
>            * Exception retournée si une erreur au niveau des répertoires de
>            * stockage survient (répertoire inexistant, droits d'accès
>            * insuffisants, etc.)
>            */
>           e.printStackTrace();
>           throw new Exception("Erreur de configuration du serveur.");
>       } catch (ServletException e) {
>           /*
>            * Exception retournée si la requête n'est pas de type
>            * multipart/form-data.
>            */
>           e.printStackTrace();
>           throw new Exception(
>                   "Ce type de requête n'est pas supporté, merci d'utiliser le formulaire prévu pour envoyer votre fichier.");
>       }
>
>       return nomFichier;
>   }
>
>   private void setErreur(String champ, String message) {
>       erreurs.put(champ, message);
>   }
>
>   private static String getValeurChamp(HttpServletRequest request,
>           String nomChamp) {
>       String valeur = request.getParameter(nomChamp);
>       if (valeur == null || valeur.trim().length() == 0) {
>           return null;
>       } else {
>           return valeur;
>       }
>   }
>
>   /*
>    * Méthode utilitaire qui a pour unique but d'analyser l'en-tête
>    * "content-disposition", et de vérifier si le paramètre "filename" y est
>    * présent. Si oui, alors le champ traité est de type File et la méthode
>    * retourne son nom, sinon il s'agit d'un champ de formulaire classique et
>    * la méthode retourne null.
>    */
>   private static String getNomFichier(Part part) {
>       /* Boucle sur chacun des paramètres de l'en-tête "content-disposition". */
>       for (String contentDisposition : part.getHeader("content-disposition")
>               .split(";")) {
>           /* Recherche de l'éventuelle présence du paramètre "filename". */
>           if (contentDisposition.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
>               /*
>                * Si "filename" est présent, alors renvoi de sa valeur,
>                * c'est-à-dire du nom de fichier sans guillemets.
>                */
>               return contentDisposition
>                       .substring(contentDisposition.indexOf('=') + 1).trim()
>                       .replace("\"", "");
>           }
>       }
>       /* Et pour terminer, si rien n'a été trouvé... */
>       return null;
>   }
>
>   /*
>    * Méthode utilitaire qui a pour but d'écrire le fichier passé en paramètre
>    * sur le disque, dans le répertoire donné et avec le nom donné.
>    */
>   private void ecrireFichier(InputStream contenuFichier, String nomFichier,
>           String chemin) throws Exception {
>       /* Prépare les flux. */
>       BufferedInputStream entree = null;
>       BufferedOutputStream sortie = null;
>       try {
>           /* Ouvre les flux. */
>           entree = new BufferedInputStream(contenuFichier, TAILLE_TAMPON);
>           sortie = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(
>                   chemin + nomFichier)), TAILLE_TAMPON);
>
>           /*
>            * Lit le fichier reçu et écrit son contenu dans un fichier sur le
>            * disque.
>            */
>           byte[] tampon = new byte[TAILLE_TAMPON];
>           int longueur = 0;
>           while ((longueur = entree.read(tampon)) > 0) {
>               sortie.write(tampon, 0, longueur);
>           }
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           throw new Exception(
>                   "Erreur lors de l'écriture du fichier sur le disque.");
>       } finally {
>           try {
>               sortie.close();
>           } catch (IOException ignore) {
>           }
>           try {
>               entree.close();
>           } catch (IOException ignore) {
>           }
>       }
>   }
>
>   private static void createORupdate(Utilisateur u, HttpServletRequest request) {
>       Session s = HibernateUtils.getSession();
>       Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
>       Query q = s
>               .createQuery("from Utilisateur where Utilisateur_email = :email");
>       q.setString("email", u.getEmail());
>       Utilisateur userUpdt = (Utilisateur) q.uniqueResult();
>
>       if (userUpdt != null) {
>           userUpdt.setNom(u.getNom());
>           userUpdt.setEmail(u.getEmail());
>           userUpdt.setSiteweb(u.getSiteweb());
>           userUpdt.setLocalisation(u.getLocalisation());
>           userUpdt.setDescription(u.getDescription());
>           s.update(userUpdt);
>       } else {
>           SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat(
>                   "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
>           Date aujourdhui = new Date();
>           u.setDateInscrit(formater.format(aujourdhui));
>           s.persist(u);
>       }
>
>       tx.commit();
>   }
>
>   private void validationEmail(String email) throws Exception {
>       UtilisateurDAO<Utilisateur, String> ud = new UtilisateurDAO<Utilisateur, String>();
>       if (ud.findByID(email) != null)
>           throw new Exception("Adresse mail déjà utilisée.");
>       else if (email == null || ud.findByID(email) != null
>               || !email.matches("([^.@]+)(\\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\\.)+([^.@]+)")) {
>           throw new Exception("Merci de saisir une adresse mail valide.");
>       }
>   }
>
>   private void validationMotsDePasse(String motDePasse, String confirmation)
>           throws Exception {
>       if (motDePasse != null && confirmation != null) {
>           if (!motDePasse.equals(confirmation)) {
>               throw new Exception(
>                       "Les mots de passe entrés sont différents, merci de les saisir à nouveau.");
>           } else if (motDePasse.length() < 6) {
>               throw new Exception(
>                       "Les mots de passe doivent contenir au moins 6 caractères.");
>           }
>       } else {
>           throw new Exception(
>                   "Merci de saisir et confirmer votre mot de passe.");
>       }
>   }
>
>   private static void validationNom(String nom) throws Exception {
>       UtilisateurDAO<Utilisateur, String> ud = new UtilisateurDAO<Utilisateur, String>();
>       if (ud.findByNom(nom) != null)
>           throw new Exception("Nom d'utilisateur déjà utilisée.");
>       else if (nom == null || nom.length() < 3) {
>           throw new Exception(
>                   "Le nom d'utilisateur doit contenir au moins 3 caractères.");
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

**InscriptionForm**

> ```
> package com.forum.servlets;
>
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
> import java.util.Date;
>
> import javax.servlet.ServletException;
> import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
> import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
> import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
> import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
>
> import com.forum.beans.Connecte;
> import com.forum.beans.Nombres;
> import com.forum.beans.Utilisateur;
> import com.forum.dao.ConnecteDAO;
> import com.forum.dao.NombresDAO;
> import com.forum.dao.UtilisateurDAO;
> import com.forum.form.InscriptionForm;
>
>
> public class Inscription extends HttpServlet {
>   public static final String ATT_USER = "utilisateur";
>   public static final String ATT_FORM = "form";
>   public static final String VUE = "/WEB-INF/inscription.jsp";
>
>   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
>           throws ServletException, IOException {
>       NombresDAO<Nombres, Integer> nd = new NombresDAO<Nombres, Integer>();
>       SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
>       Date aujourdhui = new Date();
>       Nombres n = nd.findByDay(formater.format(aujourdhui).replace("-", ""));
>       if (n == null) {
>           n = new Nombres(1);
>           nd.create(n);
>       } else {
>           n.setNbvisiteurs(n.getNbvisiteurs() + 1);
>           nd.update(n);
>       }
>
>       this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE)
>               .forward(request, response);
>   }
>
>   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
>           throws ServletException, IOException {
>       HttpSession session = request.getSession();
>
>       InscriptionForm form = new InscriptionForm();
>
>       Utilisateur utilisateur = form.inscrireUtilisateur(request);
>
>       Connecte c = new Connecte(utilisateur.getNom());
>       ConnecteDAO<Connecte, String> cd = new ConnecteDAO<Connecte, String>();
>       if (cd.findByID(utilisateur.getNom()) != null)
>           cd.update(c);
>       else
>           cd.create(c);
>       cd.findAll5();
>
>       request.setAttribute(ATT_FORM, form);
>
>       if (!form.getErreurs().isEmpty()) {
>           request.setAttribute(ATT_USER, utilisateur);
>           this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE)
>                   .forward(request, response);
>       } else {
>           UtilisateurDAO<Utilisateur, String> ud = new UtilisateurDAO<Utilisateur, String>();
>           ud.create(utilisateur);
>           session.setAttribute(ATT_USER, utilisateur);
>           response.sendRedirect("/projetForum/listforums");
>       }
>
>   }
> }
> ```

Can someone help please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Comment: Thank you BalusC, I've just seen your comment !

Comment: @BalusC, I've followed this [link](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/11/multipartfilter.html) to rebuild my form and filter. But, when I try to display the written image (uploaded file), the image isn't displayed correctly (as a broken link), can you help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, you cannot get the request parameter values directly by using `request.getParameter("param");`. This will always return null. To extract the form data, you can use [Apache commons fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/). Here is how it works ([from Commons fileUpload user guide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html)):

> A file upload request comprises an ordered list of items that are
>   encoded according to RFC 1867, "Form-based File Upload in HTML".Each
>   file item has a number of properties that might be of interest for
>   your application. For example, every item has a name and a content
>   type, and can provide an InputStream to access its data. On the other
>   hand, you may need to process items differently, depending upon
>   whether the item is a regular form field - that is, the data came from
>   an ordinary text box or similar HTML field - or an uploaded file. The
>   FileItem interface provides the methods to make such a determination,
>   and to access the data in the most appropriate manner.

[Here](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/11/multipartfilter.html) is a good article to deal with `multipart/form-data`.